# Who invented the concept of over-fitting?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, terminology, reference-request, history

I list the references that I found so far.
Shortly, the first appearance of the term was in 1670, first appearance in in close meaning was in 1827, first appearance in a biological paper was in 1923 and first appearance in statistics was in 1935.
However, the references indicate that there are gaps in this chronology.

Earliest reference I found was [The flying pen-man; or, The art of short-writing](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=KW4CAAAAQAAJ&pg=PP22&dq=overfitting&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikqNOW16ntAhWKjKQKHdaHB7IQ6AEwCHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) by William Hopkins (teacher of stenography.) in 1670.
However, it is a table of words with "overfit" as one of them and the context or meaning is not clear.

I check the other references before 1800 and those were transcription errors, "over, fit" or "overfet".

The earliest appearance in context I found was in "[The Enigmatical Entertainer and Mathematical Associate](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=c702AAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA101&dq=overfitting&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBtOiR36ntAhXH2aQKHZZmAW0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) ..., Issue 1" in 1827 saying:
"I , though for poetry not overfit , 7 Will boldly dare to lay down rules for wit ;" hence the meaning of overfit here is "fit too well" but in a positive meaning.

It seems that Darwin's "[On the Origin of Species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Origin_of_Species)" in 1859 made the concept of fitting popular.

Bray, Charles I. "[Fitting livestock for show](https://mountainscholar.org/bitstream/handle/10217/6969/COAB_62708235.pdf?sequence=1)." Bulletin (Colorado Agricultural College. Extension Service); 171A (1923). : "They believe
that these are almost equally valuable, and that there is less
danger of over-fitting the pigs than with whole milk."

The 1934 paper [Twenty-Two Years of the Eastern Percheron Futurity](https://academic.oup.com/jas/article-abstract/1934/1/121/4745091) mentions the penalty of over-fitting yet regarding stallions.

The [Quarterly Review of Biology](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/394490) Sep 1935 Volume 10, Number 3pp. 341 – 377, saying : "Perhaps we are old fashioned but to us a six-variate analysis based on thirteen observations seems rather like overfitting".
So it was well known and maybe a bit old-fashioned during 1935 already.

First statistics reference to over fitting I found appears in "[Tests of Fit in Time Series](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2334027?seq=1)", 1952.
Yet it says: " Such a graduation implies a gross
overfitting, but this can be allowed for."
Using overfitting as a well known concept.

The wikipedia article on [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) references to Oxford dictionary [entry](https://www.lexico.com/definition/overfitting) that claims: "Origin 1930s; earliest use found in Quarterly Review of Biology. From over- + fitting."

It is possible that the reference is [The Quarterly Review of Biology](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/394490) Sep 1935 Volume 10, Number 3pp. 341 – 377, yet I couldn't verify it.

I couldn't find the paper in Google Scholar.
Looking in Google ngram viewer it seems that the [usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overfitting&year_start=1885&year_end=1900&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coverfitting%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Coverfitting%3B%2Cc0) started around 1885.
Looking at Google book for that period shows [references](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22overfitting%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1900&tbm=bks) about sheep.

I'll be happy to learn that sheep are the origin of a central concept in AI but I'd like to see references.
Reference not related to sheep are welcome too.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Google ngram viewer but is it showing on this graph that there was some usage of this word in the 18th century? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overfitting&year_start=1700&year_end=1800&corpus=26&smoothing=0&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coverfitting%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Coverfitting%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Nice! I updated the question by that.

Answer (score 6):

Yes! It seems like first statistics reference to over fitting appears in [The Quarterly Review of Biology](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/394490)  . It says
"Perhaps we are old
fashioned but to us a six-variate analysis
based on thirteen observations seems rather
like `overfitting`.

I am attaching the screenshot of that particular page for your reference.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Cool! The range is smaller now. However, they also refer to overfitting like a well known concept. It probably appeared earlier. Thanks!